# How to read parquet in rdd using spark in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet

I have a .parquet file and I want to put the content in a JavaRDD, can I do that using sparkContext only? I mean, a solution could be using sparkSession and Dataset and convert them in RDD, but I would like not to use sparkSQL.